# Boost Variant conversion error when using visitor

Tags: c++, boost, operator-overloading, sfinae, static-visitor

I don't mean to code dump but this is genuinely the smallest reproducible example of this I could create even after removing all the logic to make it clearer.

Essentially I'm trying to implement my own version of some of the base types in C++ to mimic dynamic typing by storing the types in a boost::variant called `Values` and using `boost::static_visitor`s to perform operations on the `Value` variant. One operation I'm trying to implement is the the `not equals` operator, and I have created a visitor called `Not_Equal` to achieve this. The `Not_Equal` operator uses SFINAE with a `low_priority` and `high_priority` struct to determine if the two types used in the operation are allowed.

The types in the `Values` variant are: {`SpecialInt`, `SpecialBoolean`, `std::shared_ptr<SeriesInt>`, `std::shared_ptr<SeriesBoolean>`}.
The reason why the `SeriesInt` and `SeriesBoolean` are smart pointers is because they store a lot of information in my real version so copying them will be expensive.

The accepted != operators are as follows:

```
SpecialInt != SpecialInt
SpecialBoolean != SpecialBoolean
SeriesInt != SpecialInt
SeriesInt != SeriesInt
SeriesBoolean != SeriesBoolean
```

as represented by the operator overloads in each class.

```
#include <memory>
#include <boost/variant/static_visitor.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

class SpecialBoolean  {
public:

    SpecialBoolean(bool val) {} //removing this line fixes it
    SpecialBoolean()  {}

    SpecialBoolean operator!= (const SpecialBoolean& rhs) const {
        return *this;
    }

};

class SpecialInt {
public:

    SpecialInt(float val) {} //removing this line fixes it
    SpecialInt() {}

    SpecialBoolean operator!= (const SpecialInt& rhs) const {
        return SpecialBoolean();
    }

};

class SeriesBoolean {
public:

    SeriesBoolean() {}

    std::shared_ptr<SeriesBoolean> operator!= (const SpecialBoolean& rhs) const {
        return std::make_shared<SeriesBoolean>();
    }
    std::shared_ptr<SeriesBoolean> operator!= (const SeriesBoolean& rhs) const {
        return std::make_shared<SeriesBoolean>();
    }

};

class SeriesInt {
public:
    
    SeriesInt() {}
    
    std::shared_ptr<SeriesBoolean> operator!= (const SpecialInt& rhs) const {
        return std::make_shared<SeriesBoolean>();
    }
    std::shared_ptr<SeriesBoolean> operator!= (const SeriesInt& rhs) const {
        return std::make_shared<SeriesBoolean>();
    }

};

typedef boost::variant <SpecialInt, SpecialBoolean, std::shared_ptr<SeriesInt>, std::shared_ptr<SeriesBoolean> > Values;

struct low_priority {};
struct high_priority : low_priority {};

struct Not_Equal : public boost::static_visitor<Values> {

    auto operator() (Values const& a, Values const& b) const {
        return boost::apply_visitor(*this, a, b);
    }

    template <typename T, typename U>
    auto operator() (high_priority, T a, U b) const -> decltype(Values(a != b)) {
        return a != b; // problem here
    }

    template <typename T, typename U>
    auto operator() (high_priority, std::shared_ptr<T> a, std::shared_ptr<U> b) const -> decltype(Values(*a != *b)) {
        return *a != *b;
    }

    template <typename T, typename U>
    auto operator() (high_priority, std::shared_ptr<T> a, U b) const -> decltype(Values(*a != b)) {
        return *a != b;
    }

    template <typename T, typename U>
    Values operator() (low_priority, T, U) const {
        throw std::runtime_error("Incompatible arguments");
    }

    template <typename T, typename U>
    Values operator() (T a, U b) const {
        return (*this)(high_priority{}, a, b);
    }
};
```

The problem occurs in the visitor at line `return a != b;` , where the operator types are not shared_ptr's and therefore either `SpecialInt` or `SpecialBoolean` which causes the errors:

> Error  C2446   '!=': no conversion from 'SeriesInt *' to 'SeriesBoolean *'

> Error  C2446   '!=': no conversion from 'SeriesBoolean *' to 'SeriesInt *'

I don't understand what it has to do with `SeriesBoolean*` or `SeriesInt*` since it can only accept types of `SpecialInt` and `SpecialBoolean`, but I've noticed that when I remove the constructors which take a argument in `SpecialInt` and `SpecialBoolean` that the code compiles and runs as normal. I need those constructors to load values into the classes (logic removed) so my question is why am I getting these errors and how can I fix this?

Comment: The `high_priority` trick is not SFINAE (but more like tag-dispatch). Also, you don't need it here, see my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contructors for your types lead to ambiguous variant initializers.

If you can, consider making them explicit.

Also, the decltype return types don't really make sense since the visitor returns `Values` by definition.

This overload

```
template <typename T, typename U>
Values operator()(high_priority, T a, U b) const {
    return a != b; // problem here
}
```

matches ALL combinations. `operator !=` is /not defined/ in such cases. Did you mean to do:

```
template <typename T>
Values operator()(high_priority, T const& a, T const& b) const {
    return a != b; // problem here
}
```

Now you need the following overload as well:

```
template <typename T>
Values operator()(high_priority, std::shared_ptr<T> const& a, std::shared_ptr<T> const& b) const {
    return *a != *b;
}
```

Otherwise two identical shared_pointer argument types would be ambiguous.

This overload seems wrong:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
Values operator()(high_priority, std::shared_ptr<T> const& a, std::shared_ptr<U> const& b) const {
    return *a != *b;
}
```

This will obviously lead to problems because it will e.g. compare `SeriesInt` to `SeriesBool` which isn't implemented. Since it's not on your list, drop it.

Likewise, since

```
template <typename T, typename U>
Values operator()(high_priority, std::shared_ptr<T> const& a, U const& b) const {
    return *a != b;
}
```

also matches e.g [ T = SeriesInt, U = SpecialBoolean ], it will not compile.

### SIMPLIFY!

I would basically run down the list of supported overloads and just **explicitly** implement them. I'll use the above templates only for the cases that are 1:1.

> Note that consistently (!) taking args by const& make the execution a lot more efficient especially for the shared pointers.

```
struct Not_Equal : boost::static_visitor<Values> {
    Values operator()(Values const& a, Values const& b) const {
        return boost::apply_visitor(*this, a, b);
    }

    // SpecialInt     != SpecialInt
    // SpecialBoolean != SpecialBoolean
    template <typename T>
    Values operator()(T const& a, T const& b) const {
        return a != b;
    }

    // SeriesInt      != SeriesInt
    // SeriesBoolean  != SeriesBoolean
    template <typename T>
    Values operator()(std::shared_ptr<T> const& a, std::shared_ptr<T> const& b) const {
        return *a != *b;
    }

    // SeriesInt      != SpecialInt
    Values operator()(std::shared_ptr<SeriesInt> const& a, SpecialInt const& b) const {
        return *a != b;
    }

    template <typename... T>
    Values operator()(T const&...) const {
        throw std::runtime_error("Incompatible arguments");
    }
};
```

### Live Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/718632986f509457)**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/static_visitor.hpp>
#include <memory>

struct SpecialBoolean {
    explicit SpecialBoolean(bool /*val*/ = false) {}

    SpecialBoolean operator!=(const SpecialBoolean& /*rhs*/) const { return *this; }
};

struct SpecialInt {
    explicit SpecialInt(float /*val*/ = 0) {}

    SpecialBoolean operator!=(const SpecialInt& /*rhs*/) const {
        return SpecialBoolean();
    }
};

struct SeriesBoolean {
    SeriesBoolean() {}

    std::shared_ptr<SeriesBoolean> operator!=(const SpecialBoolean& /*rhs*/) const {
        return std::make_shared<SeriesBoolean>();
    }
    std::shared_ptr<SeriesBoolean> operator!=(const SeriesBoolean& /*rhs*/) const {
        return std::make_shared<SeriesBoolean>();
    }
};

struct SeriesInt {
    SeriesInt() {}

    std::shared_ptr<SeriesBoolean> operator!=(const SpecialInt& /*rhs*/) const {
        return std::make_shared<SeriesBoolean>();
    }
    std::shared_ptr<SeriesBoolean> operator!=(const SeriesInt& /*rhs*/) const {
        return std::make_shared<SeriesBoolean>();
    }
};

typedef boost::variant<
    SpecialInt,
    SpecialBoolean,
    std::shared_ptr<SeriesInt>,
    std::shared_ptr<SeriesBoolean>
  >
  Values;

struct Not_Equal : boost::static_visitor<Values> {
    Values operator()(Values const& a, Values const& b) const {
        return boost::apply_visitor(*this, a, b);
    }

    // SpecialInt     != SpecialInt
    // SpecialBoolean != SpecialBoolean
    template <typename T>
    Values operator()(T const& a, T const& b) const {
        return a != b;
    }

    // SeriesInt      != SeriesInt
    // SeriesBoolean  != SeriesBoolean
    template <typename T>
    Values operator()(std::shared_ptr<T> const& a, std::shared_ptr<T> const& b) const {
        return *a != *b;
    }

    // SeriesInt      != SpecialInt
    Values operator()(std::shared_ptr<SeriesInt> const& a, SpecialInt const& b) const {
        return *a != b;
    }

    template <typename... T>
    Values operator()(T const&...) const {
        throw std::runtime_error("Incompatible arguments");
    }
};

int main() {
}
```

### BONUS

Also, I think you should encapsulate the *optimization* of using shared_ptr<>, eliminating all your special cases.

This simplifies all of the above to:

```
struct Not_Equal : boost::static_visitor<Values> {
    Values operator()(Values const& a, Values const& b) const {
        return boost::apply_visitor(*this, a, b);
    }

    template <typename T>
    Values operator()(T const& a, T const& b) const { return a != b; }
    Values operator()(SeriesInt const& a, SpecialInt const& b) const { return a != b; }
    Values operator()(SeriesBoolean const& a, SpecialBoolean const& b) const { return a != b; }

    template <typename... T>
    Values operator()(T const&...) const {
        throw std::runtime_error("Incompatible arguments");
    }
};
```

Here's a complete demo with testcases for that **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/156e47ddac027501)**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/static_visitor.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

struct SpecialBoolean {
    explicit SpecialBoolean(bool val = false) : val(val) {}
    SpecialBoolean operator!=(const SpecialBoolean& rhs) const { return SpecialBoolean{val != rhs.val}; }
  private:
    bool val;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, SpecialBoolean const& b) { return os << "SpecialBoolean{" << std::boolalpha << b.val << "}"; }
};

struct SpecialInt {
    explicit SpecialInt(float val = false) : val(val) {}
    SpecialBoolean operator!=(const SpecialInt& rhs) const { return SpecialBoolean{val != rhs.val}; }
  private:
    float val;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, SpecialInt const& i) { return os << "SpecialInt{" << i.val << "}"; }
};

struct SeriesBoolean {
    SeriesBoolean operator!=(const SpecialBoolean& /*rhs*/) const { return {}; } // TODO
    SeriesBoolean operator!=(const SeriesBoolean& /*rhs*/) const { return {}; } // TODO

  private:
    struct VeryLarge {
        std::array<SpecialBoolean, 512> _it_is;
    };
    std::shared_ptr<VeryLarge> _data = std::make_shared<VeryLarge>();
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, SeriesBoolean const&) { return os << "SeriesBoolean{...}"; }
};

struct SeriesInt {
    SeriesBoolean operator!=(const SpecialInt& /*rhs*/) const { return {}; }
    SeriesBoolean operator!=(const SeriesInt& /*rhs*/) const { return {}; }

  private:
    struct VeryLarge {
        std::array<SpecialInt, 512> _it_is;
    };
    std::shared_ptr<VeryLarge> _data = std::make_shared<VeryLarge>();
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, SeriesInt const&) { return os << "SeriesInt{...}"; }
};

using Values = boost::variant< SpecialInt, SpecialBoolean, SeriesInt, SeriesBoolean >;

struct Not_Equal : boost::static_visitor<Values> {
    Values operator()(Values const& a, Values const& b) const {
        return boost::apply_visitor(*this, a, b);
    }

    template <typename T>
    Values operator()(T const& a, T const& b) const { return a != b; }
    Values operator()(SeriesInt const& a, SpecialInt const& b) const { return a != b; }
    Values operator()(SeriesBoolean const& a, SpecialBoolean const& b) const { return a != b; }

    template <typename... T>
    Values operator()(T const&...) const {
        throw std::runtime_error("Incompatible arguments");
    }
};

int main() {
    Values const vv[] = {
        SpecialInt(42),
        SpecialInt(-314e-2),
        SpecialBoolean(false),
        SpecialBoolean(true),
        SeriesInt(),
        SeriesBoolean()
    };

    Not_Equal const neq;

    auto col = [](auto const& v, bool right = false) -> auto& {
        std::ostringstream ss; // just for quick formatting
        ss << v;

        if (right)
            std::cout << std::right;
        else
            std::cout << std::left;
        return std::cout << std::setw(21) << ss.str();
    };

    for (auto const& a: vv) for (auto const& b: vv) try {
        col(a, true) << " != ";
        col(b) << " --> ";
        col(neq(a, b)) << "\n";
    } catch(std::exception const& e) {
        col(e.what()) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Printing

```
       SpecialInt{42} != SpecialInt{42}        --> SpecialBoolean{false}
       SpecialInt{42} != SpecialInt{-3.14}     --> SpecialBoolean{true} 
       SpecialInt{42} != SpecialBoolean{false} --> Incompatible arguments
       SpecialInt{42} != SpecialBoolean{true}  --> Incompatible arguments
       SpecialInt{42} != SeriesInt{...}        --> Incompatible arguments
       SpecialInt{42} != SeriesBoolean{...}    --> Incompatible arguments
    SpecialInt{-3.14} != SpecialInt{42}        --> SpecialBoolean{true} 
    SpecialInt{-3.14} != SpecialInt{-3.14}     --> SpecialBoolean{false}
    SpecialInt{-3.14} != SpecialBoolean{false} --> Incompatible arguments
    SpecialInt{-3.14} != SpecialBoolean{true}  --> Incompatible arguments
    SpecialInt{-3.14} != SeriesInt{...}        --> Incompatible arguments
    SpecialInt{-3.14} != SeriesBoolean{...}    --> Incompatible arguments
SpecialBoolean{false} != SpecialInt{42}        --> Incompatible arguments
SpecialBoolean{false} != SpecialInt{-3.14}     --> Incompatible arguments
SpecialBoolean{false} != SpecialBoolean{false} --> SpecialBoolean{false}
SpecialBoolean{false} != SpecialBoolean{true}  --> SpecialBoolean{true} 
SpecialBoolean{false} != SeriesInt{...}        --> Incompatible arguments
SpecialBoolean{false} != SeriesBoolean{...}    --> Incompatible arguments
 SpecialBoolean{true} != SpecialInt{42}        --> Incompatible arguments
 SpecialBoolean{true} != SpecialInt{-3.14}     --> Incompatible arguments
 SpecialBoolean{true} != SpecialBoolean{false} --> SpecialBoolean{true} 
 SpecialBoolean{true} != SpecialBoolean{true}  --> SpecialBoolean{false}
 SpecialBoolean{true} != SeriesInt{...}        --> Incompatible arguments
 SpecialBoolean{true} != SeriesBoolean{...}    --> Incompatible arguments
       SeriesInt{...} != SpecialInt{42}        --> SeriesBoolean{...}   
       SeriesInt{...} != SpecialInt{-3.14}     --> SeriesBoolean{...}   
       SeriesInt{...} != SpecialBoolean{false} --> Incompatible arguments
       SeriesInt{...} != SpecialBoolean{true}  --> Incompatible arguments
       SeriesInt{...} != SeriesInt{...}        --> SeriesBoolean{...}   
       SeriesInt{...} != SeriesBoolean{...}    --> Incompatible arguments
   SeriesBoolean{...} != SpecialInt{42}        --> Incompatible arguments
   SeriesBoolean{...} != SpecialInt{-3.14}     --> Incompatible arguments
   SeriesBoolean{...} != SpecialBoolean{false} --> SeriesBoolean{...}   
   SeriesBoolean{...} != SpecialBoolean{true}  --> SeriesBoolean{...}   
   SeriesBoolean{...} != SeriesInt{...}        --> Incompatible arguments
   SeriesBoolean{...} != SeriesBoolean{...}    --> SeriesBoolean{...}
```

Comment: Also, I think you should encapsulate the _optimization_ of using shared_ptr<>, eliminating all your special cases, [complete with 36 testcases](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74cea77ad037ff65)

Comment: Ironically, with the simplifications you *can* suddenly just SFINAE on `a!=b`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed58cdebf04af047

Comment: Cheers. I had a minor typo there in the `operator<<` implementation. [fixed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/156e47ddac027501) and the [Sfinae variant](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cc42aad041d6f31) too

Comment: Spotted! You've suggested a lot of good changes that are making it a lot easier to work with, such as the encapsulation of the shared_ptr. Can't believe I didn't think of that. Just a query, why would you recommend using explicit for the constructor?

Comment: It avoids unexpected implicit conversions. You won't run into it easily after the simplifications, but the visitor is prone to them (because the first overload takes `(Values const&, Values const&)` inviting unexpected conversions. Note: you can avoid this confusion by separating the variant dispatch from your visitor overloads. I ran into that recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65063622/boostvariant-apply-static-visitor-to-certain-types/65064425#comment115029175_65064425) where I also explain how I usually fix/avoid it.

Comment: Thank you. Also you mentioned that its best for performance to pass std::shared_ptr as a const&. Is this specific to shared_ptr (and other smart pointers) because it it is not a pod and therefore has  expensive copy operations?

Comment: "expensive" is relative, but yes: non-[trivial](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial) means that the overhead could be more than you like, especially [on platforms where the reference count is not lockfree (ad 1)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic). Basically, if you don't intend to share (and immediately unshare) ownership, either pass `shared_ptr<T> const&` or, better yet, just `T const&` :)

Comment: bless you for all the help you've provided, I really appreciate it!